# Contador en funcion recursiva

Tags: c

Tengo que realizar un procedimiento recursivo que imprima esto:

> '\n'
>   -----1
>   ----2
>   ---3
>   --4
>   -5

y por ahora tengo este codigo que imprime los numeros pero no los "-" .

```
#include <stdio.h> // sprintf, scanf, ungetc, stdin


void recurrencia(int n) {

if (n > 0) {

   recurrencia(n -1);

   printf("%d\n", n);


} else printf("\n");


}


int main()

{

recurrencia(5);

return 0;

}
```

El problema está en que no puedo agregar un parametro nuevo al procedimiento ni puedo utilizar la variable n como contador.

Por lo que mi duda es: ¿Cómo registrar cada vez que entro al mismo procedimiento de manera recursiva para poder así agregar la cantidad de "-" correspondiente a la "profundidad" con la que he entrado recursivamente?

Comment: ¿Puedes utilizar otro procedimiento dentro de recurrencia(n)?

Comment: Quiero saber si se puede sin la necesidad de hacer eso tampoco. Pero de no ver una posible solución entonces ¿como lo harías con un procedimiento auxiliar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no podés cambiar el procedimiento *recurrencia(Int n)*, per sí podés usar un procedimiento auxiliar, definiría uno que me lleve un control sobre el número de recursiones para así poder imprimir los caracteres '-':

```
void auxiliar(int n, int m) {

if (n > 0) {

   auxiliar(n -1, m);
  for(int i = 0; i < m-(n-1); i++){
      printf("-");
  }
   printf("%d", n);


} else printf("\n");


}

void recurrencia(int n){
    auxiliar(n, n);
}

int main()
{
    recurrencia(5);

return 0;

}
```

Salidas:

```
// n = 5

-----1----2---3--4-5

// n = 8

--------1-------2------3-----4----5---6--7-8
```